# add product filter to listing magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a filter to the list of products.

product attribute = 'composition' in my list of products with infinite scroll is the following code

```
$category_query = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
Mage::register('current_category', $category_query);
$return = $this->_getReturnContent();
```

I've tried in a number of ways
example

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('composition' => $composition);
```

And does not anyone have any tips?
thanks

Comment: what are you getting in `$composition` variable?

Comment: An id $composition = $this->getRequest()->getParam('composition');

Comment: what value are getting in that variable? and are you trying to get it on Product listing page?

Comment: I am rescuing the parameter passed by the example url: "site.com/?composition=1"

I'm using "meanbee / magento-infinite-scroll" and in the list of products it does not include the past parameters. as product filters.

file in question: "https://github.com/meanbee/magento-infinite-scroll/blob/develop/app/code/community/Meanbee/InfiniteScroll/controllers/AjaxController.php"

I just need to do the search as it is plus including the past filters.

Comment: line 11 and 12   https://github.com/meanbee/magento-infinite-scroll/blob/develop/app/code/community/Meanbee/InfiniteScroll/controllers/AjaxController.php

Comment: Typo in `->addFieldToFilter('composition' => $composition);`? Use comma instead of `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('composition',$composition);
```

Make Sure that attribute `composition` is added in admin.

Comment: I have already tried this code and it generates the following error. "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getPathInStore()"

Comment: the attribute has already been added in admin and is working

Comment: $_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', $category_id)->addAttributeToFilter('composicao', $composicao);
$_testproductCollection->load();

Comment: this generates error as well. more is what I need the condition with category id and attribute